# Adding files to Linux readonly-root

Tags: centos, readonly, root-filesystem

I've a netboot Linux server where the the `/root` is mounted as readonly.

```
# Set to 'yes' to mount the system filesystems read-only.
READONLY=yes
# Set to 'yes' to mount various temporary state as either tmpfs
# or on the block device labelled RW_LABEL. Implied by READONLY
TEMPORARY_STATE=yes
# Place to put a tmpfs for temporary scratch writable space
RW_MOUNT=/var/lib/stateless/writable
# Label on local filesystem which can be used for temporary scratch space
RW_LABEL=stateless-rw
# Options to use for temporary mount
RW_OPTIONS=
# Label for partition with persistent data
STATE_LABEL=stateless-state
# Where to mount to the persistent data
STATE_MOUNT=/var/lib/stateless/state
# Options to use for peristent mount
STATE_OPTIONS=
CLIENTSTATE=
```

I can see the files/directories on `/etc/rwtab` mounted in the temporary read-write filesystem. Now I would like to add files/directories to this list `/etc/rwtab` and unable to do so as itself readonly.

Now, I need to install software and update some configurations. Do I have to remount the root partition.

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
```

This is a Production server.

Comment: OP is apparently using a [RHEL/CentOS feature called "Stateless Linux"](http://plone.lucidsolutions.co.nz/linux/io/using-centos-5.2-stateless-linux-support-on-a-flash-based-root-filesystem).

Comment: Why would you use this on a production server? It sounds like it's designed for live images (ie. Linux running from a CD), *not* for a system installed on a harddisk that you want to update.

Comment: Martin, assuming you have a build pipeline for your OS build automation, this would actually be a great way to ensure consistency in a production environment, assuming you do not allow for too many things to be in that state/tmpfs overlay.  This would probably also be quite useful in VM environments such as OpenStack that have a build pipeline for the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a stateless Linux, the actual /root is mounted through NFS from a separate machine where files are obviously mounted as rw. Thanks to @Martin von Wittich

Answer (score 0):

On the system serving out / over nfs:

```
yum --installroot=<shared nfs root directory> update||install||erase <package>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! We expect answers to be more detailed here. Could you please [edit] and explain what the suggested solution does, how it works and how the OP is supposed to use it?